# GROUP BY multiple tables MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have three tables which I want to query in MySQL as follows:

**Table employee**

```
id  | name_employee
-------------------
1   | John
2   | David
3   | Sara
4   | Tina
```

**Table Status**

```
id  | name_status
-----------
1   | no process
2   | processing
3   | processed
```

**Table Ticket**

```
id  |  id_employee  |  id_status
----------------------------------
1   |        1      |     2
2   |        2      |     2
3   |        2      |     3
4   |        3      |     3
5   |        1      |     1
```

I need to query the result as follows:

```
name_employee  |  count(ticket.id) where id_status = 1 | count(ticket.id) where id_status = 2 | count(ticket.id) where id_status = 3
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
David          |          0                            |        1                             |     1   
John           |          1                            |        1                             |     0
Sara           |          0                            |        0                             |     1
```

Any help much appreciated! Thanks very much!

Comment: Please add your query/queries that you have tried.

Comment: And, as always, consider handling issues of data display in application code instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use can use case when expression

```
select name_employee,
count(case when id_status=1 then 1 end) as status1,
count(case when id_status=2 then 1 end) as status2,
count(case when id_status=3 then 1 end) as status3
from ticket_Table a
inner join employee b on a.id_employee=b.id
group by name_employee
```